# Problem with nginx + socket + flask. 504 after handshake

Tags: nginx, flask-socketio

many days trying to setup nginx + socketio + flask. After fixing many different problems I got one I can't even find in google ( *maybe I'm just too dumb, but still :)* ).
After starting all services (uWSGI + Nginx) my app becomes available and everything looks ok. Socketio makes handshake, get response 200. Still ok. After that long polling (xhr) requests start to get 504 error. In nginx error log I see that ping was sent but pong wasn't received...and after that any request starts to get 504...

Please help, I haven't more ideas where I'm wrong...

My settings:

**/etc/nginx/sites-avaliable/myproject**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomen.ru;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/myproject/ftp/files/myproject.sock;
    }

    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection ‘’upgrade’’;
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/myproject/ftp/files/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

**/etc/systemd/system/myproject.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=myproject description
After=network.target

[Service]
User=myuser
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/myproject/ftp/files
Environment=‘’PATH=/home/myproject/ftp/files/venv/bin’’
ExecStart=/home/myproject/ftp/files/venv/bin/uwsgi —ini /home/myproject/ftp/files/uwsgi.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**/home/myproject/ftp/files/uwsgi.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
module = my_module:application

master = true
gevent = 500
buffer-size = 32768
http-websockets = true

socket = myproject.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

Comment: 504 is a timeout error. Are you maybe doing long tasks in your handlers?

Comment: basically no. But problem was solved by adding "process = 1" to /uwsgi.ini as far as I got it started master process but without any workers...